# sql number login and create sql query

Tags: sql

i have below data

```
Column
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
```

i need o/p below

```
1
1
1
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
0
```

Comment: But why?  What's the pattern here?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can do something like this...

```
SELECT IIF(id = 0, 1, 0) AS col1
FROM   (SELECT id,
               Row_number() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
        FROM   tablename) tmp
ORDER  BY rn DESC
```

Result

```
+------+
| col1 |
+------+
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    0 |
|    0 |
|    1 |
|    0 |
|    0 |
|    1 |
|    0 |
|    1 |
|    0 |
|    1 |
|    0 |
+------+
```